# Best Translation for "Faculty of Electrical Engineering"

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

I'm searching for the best, most natural and usual translation for "Faculty of Electrical Engineering" to French.

I see that there are possible false cognates, so I'm not sure if it is Faculté d'ingénierie Électrique, Faculté de Génie Électrique or something else.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you

Comment: Is that a "School" name? Which one? If so, we don't use a lot "Faculté" in France (except for some fields) less in Engineering fields. We tend to use Université instead. Is it for a CV/resumé?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose, based on my experience:

> Faculté de Génie Électrique.

In general *Génie* translates Engineering in this context.

So,

> Génie des Matériaux (Material Engineering),
>
> Génie Civil (Civil Engineering),
>
> Génie Mécanique (Mechanical Engineering),
>
> Génie des Procédés (Process Engineering)

and so on.

You may use Université but I think you will be also understood even if you use Faculté.

A useful link:

https://blogs.transparent.com/french/french-academic-vocabulary/

**EDIT**

See also the question here:

[Translation of "Engineering"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/translation-of-engineering?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also see [this](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/facult%c3%a9/32640?q=facult%c3%a9#32554) for _faculté_. Thanks!

Comment: Merci pour le lien !

Comment: "Université" is used for the whole academic school, a "Faculté" is a part of an "Université". E.g. "Université Lyon 1" but "Faculté de médecine" (which is a part of the previous).