# Translation of "Engineering"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes, académique

What are some rules of thumb for translating of the word *engineering*? When do we use *Génie* and when *Ingénierie* ?

I [know](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30057/best-translation-for-faculty-of-electrical-engineering) for instance that

- Faculté de Génie Électrique: Faculty of Electrical Engineering.
- Génie des Matériaux: Material Engineering,
- Génie Civil: Civil Engineering,
- Génie Mécanique: Mechanical Engineering,
- Génie des Procédés: Process Engineering

and so forth. But what about here:

> During the current decade in the Department of Mechanics of the
>   Technical University of Foo the area of ​​Microstructure
>   Engineering has grown and developed in depth and systematically.
>
> Au cours de la présente décennie au Département de mécanique de
>   l'Université technique de Foo, le domaine de l'*ingénierie*
>   des microstructures s'est développé de manière
>   systématique et approfondie.

Comment: Plutôt que *Au cours de la présente décennie* qui me semble peu idiomatique, je te suggère *Au cours des dix dernières années, ...*

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour la correction.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça n'a pas la même signification, de manière générale. Si on était en 2015, « au cours des dix dernières années » voudrait dire « depuis 2005 », alors que « au cours de la présente décennie » (et "during the current decade") voudrait dire « depuis 2010 ».

Comment: @Blackhole Je suis bien d'accord mais je trouve que *la présente décennie* sonne un peu faux et ma suggestion tient bien sûr compte du fait qu'on est en 2019, donc la dernière année de la *current decade*,

Comment: 'Materials Engineering' is vastly more common than 'Material Engineering' (except at Oxford).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il ne semble pas y avoir de règle toute faite, par exemple [France terme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=engineering&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) recommande les deux selon le contexte.

Mon opinion tout à fait subjective est la suivante:

- *Génie* est le terme le plus ancien. Il sous-entend de plus une application assez concrète.
- *Ingénierie* semble bien plus récent, plus précisément datant des années [1960](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=ing%C3%A9nierie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cing%C3%A9nierie%3B%2Cc0) et est plus associé aux domaines pointus.

C'est pour cela que si le domaine en question est suffisamment ancien ou appliqué le mot *génie* est adapté, mais si il s'agit d'un domaine nouveau et sans application concrète répandue le mot *ingénierie* est probablement le bon choix.

Answer (score 3):

In continental France, most people do not know what "génie" means or they consider it is "building stuff" because "génie civil" is the best known expression about "génie". All your examples are actually used in naming different colleges, but they are not used in everyday conversation.

If you want to be understood, "ingénierie" is the word to use, even if most people will not know **exactly** what it means. It would be generally understood as "technology made by engineers".

Comment: Merci mais je crois avoir été clair que je m'adresse aux personnes avec des études universitaires. Si ce n'est pas le cas je m'excuse.

Answer (score 1):

'Génie' n'est utilisable que s'il est qualifié (comme dans les exemples de l'OP). 'Ingénierie' est souvent utilisé pour traduire 'Engineering' quand il est tout seul, par ex. 'des études en ingénierie' ou 'un doctorat en ingénierie'.